# .htaccess RewriteRule extra slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using this:

```
RewriteRule ^random$ ./index.php?view=random
```

It works when I access: `www.site.com/random`

But it will not work when I access: `www.site.com/random/`

When I edited the rewrite to include a slash, it makes it so `www.site.com/random/lkajsie` would work.. but ideally I only want it to work for `www.site.com/random` and `www.site.com/random/` nothing more.

Is there some kind of `regexp` to check if there's a slash in the current rewrite I have? Or is it something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex from:

```
^random$
```

to:

```
^random/?$
```

That is, make the final `/` optional.

Answer (score 0):

So .. you want it to work with and without trailing slash?

Make it (trailing slash) optional then:

```
RewriteRule ^random/?$ ./index.php?view=random
```